# How does the ISEA-projection work? Looking for a didactic algorithm description

Tags: coordinate-system, dggs, equal-earth-projection, polyhedralsurface

**Is it a direct projection on 20 faces or on 32 faces?**

Can I use PostGIS (with ISEA) to calculate and obtain cell-identifiers?  
For hexagons (like Uber H3) or for diamonds (like [DGGRID's ISEA4D](https://discreteglobal.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/dggridManualV77.pdf)).

The online literature say nothing:

- [the Wikipedia short page about ISEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snyder_equal-area_projection). No clues about algorithm. Citation into the article:
   *Begin with a Snyder Equal Area projection to a regular icosahedron (...) inscribed in a sphere (...)  Then project the hexagon back onto the sphere using the Inverse Snyder Icosahedral equal area projection*.
- [the PROJ page for ISEA](https://proj.org/en/9.2/operations/projections/isea.html), used by PostGIS and many other, would be the best source, but it doesn't say much, on the contrary, it creates some confusion by saying *"... map projections on polyhedral globes for the dodecahedron and truncated icosahedron"*. And not shows how to use each polyhedre.
- [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296900899_Snyder_equal-area_map_projection_for_polyhedral_globes) explains how to transform [regular icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) faces into projection planes and, them, into   a [Truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) of 32 faces... But I am not a good reader of mathematical formalism, nor of Chinese.

---

### NOTES

Clues by illustrations:

- ...
- Step n+1: Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection over each 20  faces of the icosahedron. 
  [image]
- Step n+2: "project back onto the sphere using the Inverse Snyder" each 5 faces to truncate, generating 12 new pentagonal faces. So, the algorithm has a [reprojection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/247775/7505) step?
  [image]
- ...

Comment: If PROJ supports it, then their source code is available. Or Snyder's Cartographica article is available for purchase.